# Azure .NET web app attempt to connect to server ''

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, azure, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET webapp deployed in Azure, as well as a Postgres DB. I have the database networking set to Public access, allow from any Azure service checked, as well as my home IP. I can successfully connect with a connection string from my local PC to the Azure database

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=mydbname.postgres.database.azure.com;Database=dbname;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123MyPass!;Ssl Mode=Allow;",
```

When I try to connect with the web app deployed in Azure, I get this error

> 2023-12-23T05:30:58.665768531Z: [INFO]  fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>
> 2023-12-23T05:30:58.665843235Z: [INFO] An error occurred using the connection to database 'dbname' on server ''.

The server hostname seems to go missing somewhere, which makes no sense at all.